# Two-Variable Polynomial Equation

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we are given $a, b, r, d \geq 0$ with $a < r$, $b < r$ and $d \leq a+b$. I would like to solve the system of equations
$$\begin{array}\,A(B^2 + r^2-b^2) &=& B(A^2 + r^2-b^2) \\
A(B^2 + r^2 - b^2)^2 &=& Br^2(A+B+d)(A+B-d) \\
B(A^2+r^2-b^2)^2 &=& Ar^2(A+B+d)(A+B-d) \end{array}$$
The last two equations are equivalent, as can easily be seen, I just put them up to emphasize the symmetry of the problem.

Any idea on how this could be done? I never worked with systems of polynomial equations.

**Motivation**: Given a circle of radius $r$ (think of a round billiard table) and the positions of two billard balls P, Q on that table, I would like to hit the ball Q with the ball P with exactly one reflection at the boundary. It seems surprisingly hard to come up with a formula that tells me in which direction I have to shoot the ball P to achieve that. The best I could come up with is the above formula in which $a$ and $b$ are the distance from the center of the circle to the balls P and Q, respectively, and $d$ is the distance between the two balls. The above formula then tells the following: Given a path from P to Q with exactly one reflection at the boundary (say at the point S), than the distances $A$ and $B$ from P to S and from S to Q, respectively fullfill the above formula. It seems to make sense that the equation is of degree $4$ in each variable, as experimental evidence (Geogebra) suggests that there are always between $2$ and $4$ solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resultant of the polynomials corresponding to equations 1 and 2 with respect to $B$ is, according to Maple,
$$
{A}^{2} \left( b-r \right)  \left( b+r \right)  \left( {A}^{4}-2\,{A}^
{2}{b}^{2}-2\,{r}^{2}{A}^{2}+{b}^{4}-2\,{b}^{2}{r}^{2}+{d}^{2}{r}^{2}+
{r}^{4} \right)  \left( b{A}^{2}-drA-{b}^{3}+b{r}^{2} \right)  \left( 
b{A}^{2}+drA-{b}^{3}+b{r}^{2} \right) 
$$
so either $A = 0$, or is a root of a quadratic in $b$, $r$ and $d$, or $A^2$ is a root of a quadratic in $b$, $r$ and $d$.